# AngularJS states and dynamic templates based on criteria

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to use AngularJS + ui-router in my project, it is working tho but I am in the middle of a situation here...

I have a HOME state with url `/`, and that state needs to do the following:

When user is NOT logged in, I want to show a full page with a login form and some different `index.html` because I don't need some columns and stuff.

When the user IS logged, then the default index.html should be used so I can use my `ui-view` grid system with all the cool stuff when a user is logged (navbar, search forms and a lot more which are in `index.html` as they must be shown in every page).

In order to check if the user is logged I have a factory `AuthFactory.isUserLogged()`

This is what I have done but is not exactly what I want...

`index.html`

```
<div ng-cloak="" ng-if="$root.globals.currentUser">
    <div class="ui fixed inverted menu">
        <div class="ui container">
            <a class="header item" href=""><img class="logo" src="">Dashboard</a>
            <a class="item">Link</a>
            <div class="right menu">
                <div class="ui dropdown icon item">
                    {{ $root.me.username }}
                    <div class="menu">
                        <a href="/settings" class="item">Settings</a>
                        <div class="divider"></div>
                        <a href="/logout" class="item">Logout</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pusher">
        <div class="full height">
            <div class="ui main container" ui-view="mainContainer"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div ng-cloak="" ng-if="!$root.globals.currentUser" ui-view="mainContainer"></div>
```

As you can see, `ui-view="mainContainer"` is declared twice in the same `index.html` one for user logged and one when not (`$root.globals.currentUser`)

`app.js`

```
$stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/',
            views: {
                'mainContainer': {
                    templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
                    controller: 'HomeCtrl',
                    controllerAs: 'vm'
                }
            }
        })
```

I know this isn't a good solution, that's why I am asking for a better one...

PS: It doesn't really matter which index.html I use, I just don't need whole markup in my not-logged-home, just a simple login form without navbar and stuff

EDIT:

This isn't working, even the `console.log`, it doesn't output anything

```
.state('home', {
            url: '/',
            views: {
                'mainContainer': {
                    templateUrl: function (AuthFactory) {
                        if (AuthFactory.isUserLogged()) {
                            console.log("yep");
                            return 'views/main.html';
                        }

                        console.log("nope");
                        return 'views/login.html';
                    }
                }
            }
        })
```

Comment: Im a newbie in angular, i created a site like you are asking for, and i used two states with ng-show, when the user is logged, the home is shown, else i show a login page

Comment: that's what I have now, but as you can see my content is rendering in the same `ui-view` for both conditions (logged and not logged in) and I think that could be better

Comment: in my case i have an ng-view, inside it i have an ui-view, with the login.html attached, and another ui.view with my home.html, i think is worth, sorry if i cant help you more :(

Comment: use a function as your template

Comment: @DanielLizik yeah, thought that too but what happens with the Controller? it should be a different one too, can I return a controller within a function just as string?

Comment: @RobertW.Hunter i would just do like `templateFn: () => loggedIn ? '<home logged-in="false">' : '<home logged-in="true">'`

Comment: see my updated question @DanielLizik

Comment: use `templateProvider`, not `templateUrl` for a function

Comment: That was what I tried before but it outputs a raw `views/login.html` string, exactly that, not the render. `templateProvider` is used to return raw `html` like `<h1>Foo</h1>` not a template url (as far as I readed in docs)

Comment: returning a component as a string assumes you've defined that component somewhere (preferably as its own module) and *usually* assumes you're using raw-loader or something in your build to import html directly instead of using template urls

Answer (score 0):

Make two different state for login and home. When user is not logged in call login state and after login home page. Only one  on master page.
Then for later transition after login you need to define  another  on home html page.

```
$stateProvider
                .state('login',
                {
                    url: '/login',
                    templateUrl: "Account/Login.html",
                    controller: 'LoginController'
                })
                .state('home',
                {
                    url: '/home',
                    templateUrl: "Home/Home.html",
                    controller: 'HomeController'
                })
```

Comment: That was what I had before, but i don't want a `/login` page, it must be the same as home if I have a choice... If not well, maybe I need to rollback and use the login page...

Comment: If you wish to use same view then use ng-show/ ng-hide by using IsLoggedin scope. if you can share your stuffs on any online code play let's figure out there.